# creating a list of possible modifications of a sequence

Tags: list, syntax-error, bioinformatics

I am not very experienced with Python and my script gives the following error:

```
"invalid syntax in line 4"
```

I don't see the reason, maybe someone can help.

I'm trying to create a list of all possible modifications of a sequence ( like `SEQWKST`). If the letter is `"S"`, the modification would be `"phos"` . If the letter is `"K"` there are three possible modifications: `"dimeth"` `"meth"` and `"ac"`

I want to create a list with the possible modifications and their positions

```
(eg:
1,phos
4,ac
4,meth
4,meth...)
```

---

```
#!/bin/python

def createPTM (SEQWKST):
    PTMlist = []
    pos = 0
    for N in SEQWKST:
        pos += 1
        if N == "Y":
            PTM = phos
            PTM_list.extend(pos,PTM)
        elif N=="S":
            PTM = phos
            PTMlist.extend(pos,PTM) 
        elif N=="T":
            PTM = phos
            PTMlist.extend(pos,PTM)     
        elif N=="R":
            PTM = meth
            PTM_2 = dimeth
            PTMlist.extend(pos,PTM)
            PTMlist.extend(pos,PTM_2)
        elif N=="K":
            PTM = meth
            PTM_2 = dimeth
            PTM_3 = ac
            PTMlist.extend(pos,PTM)
            PTMlist.extend(pos,PTM_2)
            PTMlist.extend(pos,PTM_3)       
    return PTM_list
    print PTM_list
```

Comment: Is this the *entire* file?  If not, what does it look like around line 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are, in fact, several problems with your code, but a SyntaxError at line 4 doesn't appear to be one of them.

Note that `extend` takes a single argument (a sequence of some kind) and extends a given list with that sequence, so you need to call it with e.g. `PTM_list.extend((pos,PTM))`

You don't define `phos`, `meth`, etc, but I'm guessing these are supposed to be string objects?

You `print PTM_list` outside your function definition, where it is no longer in scope. I'm guessing you want to print the returned value of `create_PTM`

Try:

```
#!/bin/python

def createPTM (SEQWKST):
    PTM_list = []
    pos = 0
    for N in SEQWKST:
        pos += 1
        if N == "Y":
            PTM = 'phos'
            PTM_list.extend((pos,PTM))
        elif N=="S":
            PTM = 'phos'
            PTM_list.extend((pos,PTM))
        elif N=="T":
            PTM = 'phos'
            PTM_list.extend((pos,PTM))
        elif N=="R":
            PTM = 'meth'
            PTM_2 = 'dimeth'
            PTM_list.extend((pos,PTM))
            PTM_list.extend((pos,PTM_2))
        elif N=="K":
            PTM = 'meth'
            PTM_2 = 'dimeth'
            PTM_3 = 'ac'
            PTM_list.extend((pos,PTM))
            PTM_list.extend((pos,PTM_2))
            PTM_list.extend((pos,PTM_3))
    return PTM_list

print createPTM('YSRKT')
```

A more Pythonic approach is to use a dictionary instead of `if..elif` and define a function to do your specialized list extending:

```
#!/bin/python

def createPTM (SEQWKST):
    PTM_list = []

    def extend_PTM_list(pos, PTMs):
        for PTM in PTMs:
            PTM_list.extend((pos, PTM))

    d = {'Y': ['phos'],
         'S': ['phos'],
         'T': ['phos'],
         'R': ['meth', 'dimeth'],
         'K': ['meth', 'dimeth', 'ac']
        }


    for pos, N in enumerate(SEQWKST, start=1):
        extend_PTM_list(pos, d[N])

    return PTM_list

print createPTM('YSRKT')
```

Output (eg):

```
[1, 'phos', 2, 'phos', 3, 'meth', 3, 'dimeth', 4, 'meth', 4, 'dimeth', 4, 'ac', 5, 'phos']
```

Comment: thanks a lot, the code is much better now. Looks like I made a mistake when running the code, there are no error messages now